# Optimise LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I just want to optimise my LINQ, I couldn't figure out how to optimise it or do it better way...
Basically I have got a client and incident tables.

Incident has a 3 status, NEW, VERIFIED and COMPLETED.
I just want to get a list of each clients incidents with the number of each incident status.

Incident Pogress number if it is 0, it means a NEW incident, if it is 1 a VERIFIED and 2 if it is COMPLETED

This is my table

```
    IncidentID ClientID    IncidentProgress
    1             1             0
    2             1             0
    3             1             0
    4             1             1
    5             1             1
    6             1             2
    7             2             0
    8             2             1
    9             2             2
    10            2             2
```

What I need

```
    ClientID    total    New Confirmed  Completed
       1           6      3     2         1       
       2           4      1     1         2
```

I tried this`
**First Group BY Each Client**

```
            List<ReportIncidentList> list = (from incident in incidentRepository.IncidentModels
                                         join client in clientRepository.ClientModel on incident.ClientID equals client.ClientID
                                         where client.ClientStatus == true && incident.IncidentStatus == true
                                         group incident by new { client.ClientID, client.ClientName, incident.IncidentProgress } into newGroup
                                         orderby newGroup.Key.ClientID                     

                   select new ReportIncidentList
                   {
                       ClientID = newGroup.Key.ClientID,
                       ClientName = newGroup.Key.ClientName,
                       NumberOfIncidents = newGroup.Count(),
                       NewT = newGroup.Where(x=>x.IncidentProgress == Models.IncidentProgressStatus.New && x.ClientID == newGroup.Key.ClientID).Count(),
                       Completed = newGroup.Where(x => x.IncidentProgress == Models.IncidentProgressStatus.Completed && x.ClientID == newGroup.Key.ClientID).Count(),
                       Confirmed = newGroup.Where(x => x.IncidentProgress == Models.IncidentProgressStatus.Confirmed && x.ClientID == newGroup.Key.ClientID).Count(),
                       IncidentProgress =  newGroup.Key.IncidentProgress
                   }).ToList();
```

**Then Group again**

```
            List<ReportIncidentList> list2 = (from client in list
                                         group client by new { client.ClientID, client.ClientName } into newGroup
                                         orderby newGroup.Key.ClientID
                                         select new ReportIncidentList
                                         {
                                             ClientID = newGroup.Key.ClientID,
                                             ClientName = newGroup.Key.ClientName,
                                             NumberOfIncidents = list.Where(c=>c.ClientID==newGroup.Key.ClientID).Sum(s=>s.NumberOfIncidents),
                                             NewT = list.Where(x => x.IncidentProgress == Models.IncidentProgressStatus.New && x.ClientID == newGroup.Key.ClientID).Select(x=>x.NewT).SingleOrDefault(),
                                             Confirmed = list.Where(x => x.IncidentProgress == Models.IncidentProgressStatus.Confirmed && x.ClientID == newGroup.Key.ClientID).Select(x => x.Confirmed).SingleOrDefault(),
                                             Completed = list.Where(x => x.IncidentProgress == Models.IncidentProgressStatus.Completed && x.ClientID == newGroup.Key.ClientID).Select(x => x.Completed).SingleOrDefault(),
                                         }).ToList();
```

Comment: What you consider as optimization ? Is there any indication something is slow ? You think the source code of the query is too long ? Usually the SQL-Server is doing all necessary optimizations. If you are able to put all you want to do in one query, you're done. Skip the first ToList() that already helps.

Comment: Instead of immediately calling `ToList` on the result, assign the query to a temporary variable and then call `ToList` on that variable.  After the ToList call, that temporary will contain the SQL that was materialized and sent to the database.  You can then see how optimal that was (and use SQL optimization tools to see if you can do better)

Comment: HI Hoger2, I just want to know is there any better way to do it. Instead of 2 different queries maybe I can do it with a single query.

Comment: Thank you Flydog5... I will do it

Comment: As it is now, you iterate three times on your `list` temporary variable, each time to retrieve a specific status of incident. If your list gets very large and/or the number of incidents is large, this might be an expensive operation. You could create a custom function that takes a list of incidents and returns three sublists of incidents by iterating the main list only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the linq query that will get you the results:

```
var results = data
    .GroupBy(x => x.ClientID)
    .Select(g => new {
        ClientID = g.Key, 
        Total = g.Count(), 
        New = g.Count(i => i.IncidentProgress == 0), 
        Confirmed = g.Count(i => i.IncidentProgress == 1), 
        Verified = g.Count(i => i.IncidentProgress == 2)});
```

Answer (score 2):

What about keeping things simple?

We can just query list of incidents as is and merge data in a single loop then.

```
var incidents = incidentRepository.IncidentModels.ToList();

var reportsIncidentList = new Dictionary<int,ReportIncidentList>();
foreach (var incident in incidents)
{
    if (!reportsIncidentList.ContainsKey(incident.ClientID))
        reportsIncidentList.Add(incident.ClientID, new ReportIncidentList(){ClientID = incident.ClientID});

    reportsIncidentList[incident.ClientID].Total++;

    switch (incident.IncidentProcess)
    {
        case 0:
            reportsIncidentList[incident.ClientID].New++;
            break;
        case 1:
            reportsIncidentList[incident.ClientID].Confirmed++;
            break;
        case 2:
            reportsIncidentList[incident.ClientID].Completed++;
            break;
    }
}

var result = reportsIncidentList.Values.ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you yolo, when I first typed it I did exactly the way you did,  I agree it is very simple but I like challenges and I think Carlo's code is beautiful.

Comment: Carlo's code is somehow beautiful but it has the exact same bottleneck as what you provided. Keep in mind that sometimes you have to trade prettiness for performance (emphasis on the **sometimes**)